# CocoaPods TestFlight Error Library not found for -lTestFlight

Tags: cocoapods, testflight

In the pod file these are the following settings in place

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'TestFlightSDK','~> 3.0'
```

after i give "pod install" its throwing the error Library not found for -lTestFlight

Answer (score 0):

does it work with the latest version of TestFlightSDK?

`pod 'TestFlightSDK', '~> 3.0.2'`